# How to add an attribute whether a user exists or is new in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, passport.js

I'm using passport and sequelize to create/find users in my DB. This is my following code

```
const strategyCallback = (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
    return models.user.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        googleId: profile.id,
      }, defaults: {
        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        username: profile.emails[0].value.split('@')[0],
        profilePictureUrl: profile.photos[0].value
      }
    }).then(([ user, isNewUser ]) => {
        // add an attribute to the user to find out whether he is new or not
        // something like user.isNew = isNewUser?
        return cb(null, user);
    }).catch(...error handling);
};
```

Once the user is created or given back, I'd like to return a user with an attribute to figure out if he's an existing user or if he was just created. I'm doing this cause the redirect will depend on that attribute. How exactly could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The `verify` callback takes three arguments thus, complete signature would be `cb(error, user, info)` and `info` is the object that should contain additional messages as per [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/).

So, you can do this:

```
then(([ user, isNewUser ]) => {
    // add an attribute to the user to find out whether he is new or not
    // something like user.isNew = isNewUser?
    return cb(null, user, { isNew: isNewUser }); // <- Notice the info object
})
```

And then, in your controller where you are calling `passport.authenticate()` you can access the info object as follows:

```
passport.authenticate(/** your-strategy-name-here */, function(err, user, info) {
    // ... error handling
    if(info.isNew) {
        // Logic to redirect 
    } else {
       // Logic to redirect 
    }
})
```